# PHP - Change value of variable before inserting into sql - Without Ajax

Tags: php

I have the variable

```
$sql1 .= "Brukertype";
```

Which gets information set from an already-filled textbox. It can either have the value `Administrator` or the value `Iskjører`.

What is the best way to change these values before inserting them into SQL?
The `Administrator` value should get changed to the value `1` and `Iskjører` gets changed to the value `2`.

I can't use a select function (dropdown list) on the question because it needs to be enabled/disabled on my command.

Comment: Why can't use enable/disable `select` element or it's `option` elements?

Comment: Because the user also needs to be able to enter something else into the textfield if needed.
I'm pretty beginner at html/php but so far the project is working as I want, problem is that its getting too big for me to post the whole thing here I think, I'm just curious if I could solve my issue with an if statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonable place to use a switch statement. You want a 'marshaling' function, like this:

```
function marshal_input($input) {
    $result = 0;
    switch ($input){
      case 'Administrator':
          $result = 1;
          break;
      case 'Iskjører':
          $result = 2;
          break;
      case 'SomethingYouHaventThoughtOfYet':
          $result = 3;
          break;
      default:
          $result = 0;
          break;
   }
}
```

However, the implementation of the marshaling function can be almost anything:

```
function marshal_input($input) {
    $options = array("Administrator" => 1, "Iskjører" =>2);
    return $options[$input];
}
```

The point is that you need some code that *maps* from the human-readable form to the numerical representation the db needs. Then you just call it like so:

```
$sql_version = marshal_input($sql1);//Doesn't overwrite the variable
//...or...
$sql1 = marshal_input($sql1);//Note this overwrites the variable.
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have stated:

> *It can eighter have the value "Administrator" or the value "Iskjører"...*

we only check whether the value is 'Administrator' or not.

Try this:

```
$val = 'Administrator'; // user input variable
$sql_val = ($val == 'Administrator') ? 1 : 2;
```

If value is 'Administrator' set `$sql_val` to 1,  else set  `$sql_val` to 2

Comment: I would appreciate knowing the reason for down voting.